# MS Excel custom unicode function

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I have a list of IPA symbols like the following in a column in my Excel file:

```
a
ɒ
ɒ̃
ɑː
æ
aɪ
aʊ
aʊə
b
ɔː
```

I was using the unicode function to get the value for each character. This works for single characters only so I am trying to write a custom function that will return the value for each character separated by a .

However, the function doesn't recognise certain (non-alphabet) characters like ɒ̃ and æ.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I have pasted the code below:

```
Public Function UnicodeText(text2convert As String)
Dim textLen As Integer
UnicodeText = ""
textLen = Len(text2convert)

If Len(text2convert) = 1 Then
    UnicodeText = Asc(text2convert)
Else
    For i = 1 To textLen
        If i = 1 Then
           UnicodeText = UnicodeText & Asc(Left(text2convert, 1)) & "."
        Else
           If i = textLen Then
              UnicodeText = UnicodeText & Asc(Right(text2convert, 1))
           Else
              UnicodeText = UnicodeText & Asc(Mid(text2convert, i, 1)) & "."
           End If
       End If
 Next i

End If

End Function
```

Also, it recognizes the character ɒ̃ as having length 2

The reason for doing this is to make sure that the characters used are all the same as some characters like ɡ and g look the same in certain fonts but are actually 2 different characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you can use the `AscW` function. The `AscW` function returns the **Unicode** character for a string.

You can either replace the `Asc` in your code with `AscW`, or use the code below:

```
Option Explicit
Function uni(S As String) As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim sTemp As String

sTemp = ""
For I = 1 To Len(S)
    sTemp = sTemp & "." & AscW(Mid(S, I, 1))
Next I

uni = Mid(sTemp, 2)

End Function
```

[image]

By the way, if you have **O365** with the `TEXTJOIN` and `SEQUENCE` functions, you can use this worksheet formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(".",TRUE,UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))
```

If you have `TEXTJOIN` but not the `SEQUENCE` function, you can replace the `SEQUENCE` function call with `ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))`

```
=TEXTJOIN(".",TRUE,UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),1)))
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. I do not have O365 so I just used the AscW function which seems to work OK.

Answer (score 1):

### CHAR(CODE) vs UNICHAR(UNICODE)

No solution here. This is just a visual interpretation what's happening here. It shows the 'transformation' of columns `AC` with `CODE` to columns `EFG` and with `UNICODE` to columns `HIJ` and then back again with `CHAR` to columns `KLM` and with `UNICHAR` to columns `NOP`. Column `Q` represents the results of OP's function, while columns `RS` represent the results of Jon Rosenfeld's solution. Below I added the critical characters from my language.

[image]

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008.... the pic helped me to understand what was going on.